# Машинное обучение: Регрессионный анализ

Tags: машинное-обучение

Недавно прочел книгу Себастьяна Рашки Python Machine Learning , там был раздел про регрессионный анализ , почитав этот раздел мне показалось что регрессионный анализ представляет из себя альтернативу алгоритмам классификации в машинном обучении , я не совсем понимаю зачем нужен регрессионный анализ в задачах классификации если есть алгоритмы классификации , в чем их преимущество? Заранее прошу прощения за свои скудные познания , только начал изучать машинное обучение.

Comment: может быть вы имеете в виду "логистическую регрессию"?

Comment: нет не совсем, к примеру в той же книге ,про которую я говорю, есть упоминание  о классе LinearRegression в пакете sklearn для языка python , также есть RANSACRegressor и DecisionTreeRegressor которые строят более сложные регрессионные модели и на основе них проводят классификацию,  в чем их преимущество перед алгоритмами классификции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теоретически, задача классификации рассматривается как частный случай задачи построения регрессии. Но в реальных задачах каждый из методов имеет четко очерченный круг проблем, в котором их следует применять.

Практически, регрессионные модели применяются тогда,  все данные измерены в числовых шкалах. Соответственно, вы можете задать произвольные значения независимых переменных и получить значение зависимой переменной, причем область возможных ее значений - от минут до плюс бесконечность.

Классификационные модели применяются тогда, когда как минимум зависимая переменная, а возможно - и некоторые (или даже все) независимые переменные измерены в  слабых шкалах, т.е. в шкалах дихотомической, номинальной и/или ранговой.

Соответственно, если в задачах регрессии задача прогнозирования ставиться так: "каким будет значение зависимой переменной если известны значения независимых" (например - "вот набор набор лабораторных показателей, укажите предположительную длительность выздоровления пациента"), а в случае задач классификации задача будет ставиться так : "каким из заранее заданного и конечного набора возможных значение будет значение  зависимой переменной если известны значения независимых" (например - "вот набор набор лабораторных показателей, укажите диагноз заболевания")